# How to wire this “green laser module diode”?

Tags: wiring, laser

I am trying to wire a 532 nm, 5 mW green laser module rated at 3 V DC (from [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/INDUSTRIAL-LAB-532nm-5mW-3VDC-Green-Laser-DOT-Module-Diode-w-Spring-/131804313399?hash=item1eb0263737:g:P4wAAOSwimdXpC0Y#shpCntId)).

[image: Front Side]
[image: Back Side]

But how? I would assume the spring is VCC and the housing is GND, but latter is not connected to any of the two wires which go from the PCB to the laser diode, so there seems to be at least one contact missing.

Also, will I have to use a serial resistor to limit the current to 5 mW, or are the on-board device handling that already?

**Update – Solved:** The laser module was incorrectly labeled as 3VDC, but is in fact 4.2–5 V. As mentioned in [Whiskeyjacks answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/292251/135063), GND is connected to the spring and VCC to the housing.

Comment: In the meantime, the ebay page has been updated as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect GND to spring and VCC to the brass material. There is a connection trace going from housing to the component named D882. Onboard circuit will handle the power. Just keep in mind that you power it using correct rated voltage. Over voltage might damage the device.

Comment: Tried (with two AA batteries and with 3V output from an arduino UART USB board) – still nothing at all (and yes, I have pressed the button after connecting VCC and GND).

Comment: Hey, just try with GND to spring and VCC to housing. I guess these are supposed to run with AA cells and they usually give -ve side to a spring ending.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. Is it possible that all the laser modules (3/3) have arrived defective?

Comment: Haha, this is embarrassing. Contacted the seller, and he answered I should use 4.2 to 5 V. Now it works. Spring is GND.

Comment: Can't trust specs written on a webpage especially ebay. :) For a moment I was worried that you blew all of your laser modules by reverse connecting them. Luckily they had reverse voltage protection.

Answer (score 2):

The positive terminal is connected to the housing.
The housing is connected to the singe pin in on the bottom side. (The laser has 3 pins, 2 on top and 1 on the bottom)

A current limiting resistor is not needed. The module has an active current limiting circuit based around that LM358 opamp, a transitor and a shunt resistor. If you want to set the current, use the trimming potentiometer on the bottom of your module.

-Max

Comment: Many thanks for the information. I indeed did not notice the third connector to the laser!

Comment: @Max - I just googled laser modules and i feel that housing is VCC and not the GND. please check once and update your answer. I did correct mine.

Comment: You are right. Updated my answer.
Should have noticed the polarity marking of the small diode.